# Has Anyone succeeded in implementing Holoeverywhere + Slidingmenu library 100% perfect?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu, android-holo-everywhere

I have implemented it on a project and I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v4.app._HoloFragment.mChildFragmentManager` error. I am getting this error on rotating screen or when the HoloFragments onDestroyView() is called. [Details here](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/555)

The only recommendation I found online is to use the latest android-support-library.jar. Unfortunately it does not solve the issue. I have tried commenting all the codes inside the onDestroyView(), the app works fine without error but I am facing some sliding menu issues on ICS and above. Specifically the slidingmenu animation is not working on actionbar menu button press and sometimes the sliding menu content it not responding!

Did anyone faced the similar issue ? 
Any help/suggestions will be really helpful!

Comment: The crash bug is now automatically fixed. Just restarted the eclipse and now its working. Still I have issues with ICS+ devices on ActionBar home button click. It actually skips the animation on showing the page menu and the page menu is not clickable. There is no issue if i swipe to see the page menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by replacing `toggle()` with `showBehind()` !!

Now works perfectly and `showBehind()` works exactly as `toggle()` function !